# Converting a 4 channel matrix to 1 channel in Android using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I've created a matrix from a ARGB_8888 bitmap like this:

```
Mat detectedFaceMat = Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp1);
```

The resultant matrix has 4 channels. I now need to compare it to 1 channel matrices. Not sure how to convert the 4 channel to 1 (I only need grayscale).

Comment: will you use the alpha channel? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053889/how-to-convert-32-bit-rgba-image-to-grayscale-preserving-alpha

Comment: No, the alpha channel is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV supports `CV_BGRA2GRAY` with [`cv::cvtColor()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?cvtcolor#cvtcolor) or [`cvCvtColor()`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?cvtcolor#cvtcolor) which converts BGRA pixels to Grey.
It is possible that ARGB is in fact BGRA in memory (this is the most common format). In this case The above conversion will work as expected.

If not, you can always use the green channel as a pretty good approximation for grey.